# Print preset views with a CAD Viewer (AutoCAD free)

Tags: python, automation, autocad, viewer, dxf

I'm working in a program which creates the different views of a structure (isometric, top, front, and right), as you can see in Figure 1.

[image: Final plan of the structure.]

*Figure 1.* Final plan of the structure.

To achieve this sort of things, the software basically asks the user some data about the geometry and the weight the structure has to support, to then develop an internal calculation process. At the end, the user can ask the software to print the plan of the structure (AutoCAD free) in .dxf format.

This was made in Python, with the dxfwrite library. The problem I'm facing is that, as the goal of the project is to be completely *Open Source*, when I open the plan in a viewer, let's say "Autodesk DWG TrueView", initially I've got this:

[image]

*Figure 2*. Initial plan.

Comparing Figures 1 and 2 is evident that I can manually orientate the views. The problem is when I try to print the plan, because despite of the final orientation I gave to the views, it prints what's seen on Figure 2.

My question is: Does anybody know if there's a way to print the views in the correct order with this viewer? If so, how can I do it? (off course, I googled it, but I haven't found anything useful). If not, I would be thankful if you suggest me a .dxf viewer that allows me to move and print my 3D CAD in the exact position I need.

PS: I'd read the *dxfwrite* documentation, and there's a way to specify the location of views in the viewports, but I haven't found an easy way to set the preset views in the viewports (it would be useful to know how to, and would be also validated as an answer to my problem).

Comment: Maybe you consider to switch to ezdxf, which has better layout support, especially for DXF R2000 and later (Layout support for DXF R12 is still bad), look for examples/page_setup_R2000.py (author of dxfwrite and ezdxf)

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you!

On the other hand, I must say that the work you did with the dxfwrite library is a really interesting one. Thanks to it,  I'm able to make things that months ago I could have found as impossible. I know that maybe I'm asking too much, but I'd love to know how you did it... In the future, I would like to be able to make my own libraries, but I don't certanly know where to start.